# Palantir Foundry: Composite-Key for DataSet-Rows / Object-Instance Primary Key

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I have a `one-to-many` Ontology relationship where -- for a given `Alert` object-instance -- I want **at most one** `Feedback` object-instance for it per `User`. A `Feedback` object-instance is **Created** & **Updated** by `Users` using  its **Add** & **Modify** **Actions**, respectively (*and is used to provide one feedback **score** & **commentary** per `User` per `Alert` object-instance*).

As such, to implement **at most one semantics**, each `Feedback` object requires a `Primary Key` composed of:

> `feedbackID` (PK) = `alertID` (PK) + `userID` (PK)

However, in its backend definition, the `Feedback` object-type's **Add** **Action**  sets the `Primary Key` as a `UUID`, and this cannot be overwritten once instantiated. (*Note: An `object-reference` or `property` is also possible here, but either would also only be part of the `composite key` sought*). That is to say, although it's possible to synthesize the above `composite-key` in a frontend `Workshop Action Tab` (using `Workshop` `variables` and `forms`), it's understandably not possible to overwrite an object's already-existing `PK` with it.

> Indicentally, **for completeness**, I'll mention, but not necessarily recommend, a two-DataSet option for `composite-key PK` consisting of the following steps:
>
> 1. The **Add Action** creates rows for an initial DataSet with `UUID`'s as its `PK`.
> 2. A Foundry `data pipeline` mirrors this DataSet to create a corresponding DataSet with `alertID` + `userID` as its `PK`.
> 3. And finally, the **Modify Action** as well as **downstream application uses** consume that mirror (second) DataSet.
>
> Again, presented for completeness and not necessarily recommended since it duplicates DataSets, as well as adds propagation delay to the out-of-the-box platform propagation delay.

With that as preamble, is there a just-in-time technique to generate Objects with a composite-key `PK` consisting of properties from other Objects (again, at `Add`-Action click time)? I may have missed something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an interim workaround which broadly include these steps:

- Create a `Function` (snippet below) coupled with a `Function-backed Workshop variable` that returns a count of `Feedback` objects having the same `alertID` and `userID` combination (i.e. a manually synthesized `composite-key`):

> 1. If `0` is returned, only the **Add Action Button** (in green) is visible (via display logic).
> 2. If `1` is returned, only the **Modify Action Button** (in amber) is visible (via display logic).
> 3. If `> 1` is returned (*which would only happen if a bug existed somewhere*), only a **Red Error Button** is visible (via display logic), with its hover-over text instructing the user to take a screenshot and eMail developers. No Action or Event is attached to this button.

```
@Function() // Used to set a Workshop variable (0|1|>1).
public async countFeedbackRecords(alertID: string,
                                  userID: string):
                                  Promise<Integer> {

  const feedbacks = Objects.search().feedback() // Feedback object-type is imported at top-of-file.
  const count = await feedbacks.filter(obj => obj.alertId.exactMatch(alertID))
                               .filter(obj => obj.user.exactMatch(userID))
                               .count()

  return Promise.resolve(count || 0)
}
```

One downside to this approach are lookups against the two columns mentioned, which are neither hashed nor indexed.